How to share arguments in different classes?
Suppose I have a python class with arguments in the __init__ method with types specified.
class A:
    def __init__(self, arg_1:int, ..., arg_n:int):
        pass

Suppose I inherit from it as such:
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, arg_2:int, ..., arg_n:int):
        super().__init__(arg1="str", arg_2, ..., arg_n)

The problem here is that I have to write the the whole argument list including the types. If I decide to change the type of one argument to some other type, I have to do so for all subclasses. How can we avoid this?
One possible solution could be the one below. However, the constructor here does not show the list of arguments as they are defined in Class A.
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(arg1="str", **kwargs)

Is it maybe possible to group the common arguments in one class and share that in all classes?

Why not use a dataclass to create a Params object containing the arguments and instantiate both A and B with an object of class Params?

The possible solution is indeed what is recommended by https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/. Ultimately, you don't know that super().__init__ refers to A.__init__, as it depends entirely on the runtime type of self. As such, it's not really a problem that it doesn't list A's parameters, because there might be more than just A's parameters that need to be filled.
